# Does HTTP Forward request preserve the referer in the header?

Tags: java, http

I have a Java HttpServlet which uses the forward command from RequestDispatcher to send the user somewhere else sometimes. Does the HTTP Referer Header get preserved from the original request on forward? (I believe with redirect it doesnt).
My feeling is that it is preserved since I think the client never knows about the forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does, a forward inside the same server is just giving someone else the option to handle the request and the request and response objects usually go unchanged (unless you build a filter that changes these objects).

Comment: Okay, but what if it's not the same server?

Comment: You can't do a servet forward using a ResuqestDispatcher to a different server, it has to be inside the same server. You can see this at the forward method JavaDoc - http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse)

Comment: Thanks, I think I might have just found another bug... :)